# What exactly do we mean by $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives, solution-verification

My maths book says $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d(\frac{dy}{dx})}{dx}$$
I have tried to look at this by the division rule and from what I can understand, $$\frac{d(\frac{dy}{dx})}{dx}=\frac{(d^2ydx-d^2xdy)}{(dx)^2*dx}$$

I can't understand how both the equations can be equivalent, I understand I'm in the wrong but where am I going wrong? I was taught $dx$ can be thought of as a very small quantity, is there any such way to look at $d^2x$

My teacher also told me that $$\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}=\frac{dx}{dy}*\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2*\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

How can the $ d^2x\space become\space d^2y$ an equivalent would be $f''(x)\space becoming\space g''(x)$ which seems quite impossible, where am I going wrong?

Comment: It's just notation

Comment: @peek-a-boo but what does it mean exactly?

Comment: You take the 2nd derivative (with regard to x) of the function $y$.

Comment: The Leibniz notation $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is mnemonic and suggestive, and it can even be made rigorous to an extent, but without care, you can stretch it too far.  It is not, in its simplest manifestation, a fraction, but a limit of a fraction.

Comment: @BrianTung, so the rules of differentiation don't work here?

Comment: The rules of differentiation work, but $\frad{dy}{dx]$ is **not** a quotient, so you can't apply the quotient rule to it; there is no differentiable function "$dy$" and no differentiable frunction "$dx$" at play here, so you can't use a formula that is not applicable. Similarly, the qudratic formula still works, but it is not applicable to **this** situation.

Comment: What we have is $\frac{d^2y}{dx} = \frac{d(y')}{dx}$. There is no quotient.

Comment: Nothing is ever differentiated with respect to $dx$. When we write $dy/dx$ we differentiate with respect to $x.$

Comment: it represents how the slope of the graph changes whether it increases first and then decreases or maybe vice versa or maybe if the second derivative is zero then we get an inflection point which means that the graph was going one way and suddenly started going the other way

Comment: Saying it's "just notation" is fine for the daily business, but not the whole story. If you wanna dive into the rabbit hole of meaningful infinitesimal notation, you could start here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.09553.pdf.

Comment: @milten yes the pdf was useful, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is shorthand for $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{d}{dx}(y))$. It is the two-fold application of the derivative (with respect to $x$) to $y$ (which is a function of $x$). The second derivative tells you what the rate of change of the *first* derivative of $y$ is at the given $x$-value (after all, it is the first derivative *of* the first derivative of $y$).